# need border inside and over image

Tags: html, css

i want a white border inside image e.g

[image]

i tried to search in Google but din't find a proper solution

Note: no css3 , should work in IE7

Demo : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLsYd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use position `relative` for wrapper and `absolute` for border div: http://jsfiddle.net/pLsYd/11/

Comment: Using static height and width values is no good. Use `top, left, bottom, right` instead and make sure, the image has `display:block`: http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/pLsYd/17/